# How to load data into Hbase table from BIGSQL table?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, biginsights, bigsql

I am new to Hadoop Development. In our company, we are using IBM BigInsights cluster and we are working on an `HBASE` project. We have a requirement to load data from HDFS to HBASE.

To do that, I am familiar with 3 ways:

```
 1. Load data from HDFS into HIVE table and insert into HBASE table.
 2. Load data from HDFS into PIG table and insert into HBASE table.
 3. Load data directly from HDFS and insert HBASE table (Java- MapReduce Code)
```

Recently, I came to know that we can `load data from BIG SQL table into HBASE table`. I am not able to find a proper guidance/script on how can I do that. If anyone could help me with a sample script, then I would really appreciate.

Based on the results, I am trying to find out which is faster while loading data into `HBASE` ?

Comment: This [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/CynthiaSaracco/big-data-big-sql-and-hbase) has a few slides that shows how you can load from flat files to HBASE.. it involves creating HBASE tables via BigSQL and then using `load hadoop`. I am thinking you can tweak it to load data from HDFS as well..  Unsure about the speed though

Comment: wow.. this is exactly what I was looking for.. let me try this.. thanks @vmachan